# Is there any cloud API to save internet image to cloud using Python?

Tags: python, image, google-app-engine, cloud, dropbox

I have a project in hand to **backup** a website for some reasons. I use Requests in Python to crawl the contents and images (urls). The problem is, how can I save the image in the cloud, by using the url of that image, in Cloud services (Google Drive, Dropbox, etc.).

I know there is a way to first save the image locally and then upload the local image to the cloud. But I'm wondering if there are APIs that support uploading images by urls, not the local file.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like [Dropbox](https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2015/06/programmatically-saving-a-url-to-dropbox/) has a feature called `/save_url` that

> lets app developers upload files to Dropbox by just providing a URL, without having to download the file first.

https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/docs#save-url

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind paying for the storage, you can save it to your own cloud storage. I occasionally have to do a similar action, and handle it as such:

```python
def on_upload_image(self):
  url = self.request.get('url')
  result = urlfetch.fetch(url)
  binary = result.content
  blob_key = functions.get_blob_key_by_data(binary)
  self.url = images.get_serving_url(blob_key, secure_url=True)
  self.json()

from google.appengine.api import app_identity
def get_blob_key_by_data(data):
  bucket = app_identity.get_default_gcs_bucket_name()
  filename = hashlib.sha256(data).hexdigest()
  mime_type = get_mime_type(data)
  if not mime_type:
    return None

  gcs_filename = '/%s/image_%s' % (bucket, filename)
  with gcs.open(gcs_filename, 'w', content_type=mime_type) as f:
    f.write(data)

  blob_key = blobstore.create_gs_key("/gs" + gcs_filename)
  return blob_key
```